# Python: appending egrep output into a file

Tags: python, grep, append

In a Python script, I'm trying to count the number of times {H9,H10...C21,H11} appear in a group of files. I don't need counts for each individual phrase in the set, just a single sum. The filenames are contained in an array named "legend" and are sorted numerically by name.
My best attempt is below:

```
for nitem in sorted(legend, key=numericalSort):
    with open(nitem, 'a+') as f:
        with open('block.txt', 'a+') as myfile:
            var5 = 'egrep -c "H9|H10|N71|N61|H32|C81|N91|C51|C61|C41|N11|N31|C21|H11" <%s> %s' %(nitem,myfile)
            os.system(var5)
```

When I run this, I get the following error for each file contained in legend (only one error message included below):

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
sh: -c: line 0: `egrep -c "H9|H10|N71|N61|H32|C81|N91|C51|C61|C41|N11|N31|C21|H11" <file00.dat> <open file 'block.txt', mode 'a+' at 0x7f71196ec660>'
```

All I want is to append with egrep within python, but cannot do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:

```
for nitem in sorted(legend, key=numericalSort):
    with open(nitem, 'a+') as f:
        var5 = '''egrep -c "H9|H10|N71|N61|H32|C81|N91|C51|C61|C41|N11|N31|C21|H11" %s >> filename.txt''' %(nitem)
        os.system(var5)
```

Using triple quotes and not confusing python append for UNIX append seemed to do the trick.